# Windows 10 Files and Folders restored

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am using Windows 10. My file and folder contents are restored as they were 6 months ago. What should I do?

For example, I have an excel file in which I logged attendance of team members. I had updated the Excel file through October 26, 2017. When I open that excel file, it is showing data until May 1, 2017.

The same thing happened with every Word, Excel, and notepad documents. New folders and data which were created after May 1, 2017 have been deleted.

What should I do to recover file data. Is it a bug or something else?

Comment: Recuva helps to restore the data, you may try it, but I guess the backup (if present) can only help here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your system rolled back to a system image or similar from the date you mentioned. I would check the event logs to see if you can determine what happened exactly, and then you can see if it may be reversible.

Most likely, it will not be reversible, and you may need to take this as a lesson to keep important documents on a network drive. Then you can keep backups of the server to be able to roll back to.

You could also look into a desktop backup solution (Veeam Endpoint, Carbonite, etc.).